# MySQL with an intermediate SSL cert?

Tags: mysql, ssl

It seems that MySQL (5.0.77-log) does not support intermediate, or chained, SSL certificates. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [open feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54158), which was opened against 5.1, I'm gonna say no; not directly.

But, there's no reason you couldn't have, say, stunnel do the encryption for you, instead of having MySQL do it, as long as you don't need client certificate authentication - that might be a good workaround.